# amp-img images not showing on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, amp-html, amp-img

I'm having an issue with  images not loading on iPhone browsers. Works absolutely fine while testing through chrome and other browsers on Android phones. I keep getting the console error "Failed to load: *image* - v0.js:127"

Below is the html code of an image, you will see there's nothing out of the ordinary but yet the images won't load specifically on iOS devices.

```
<div class="left-column">
    <a href="test/en/amp/car/aston-martin-db9">
        <amp-img 
            src="test/assets/img/upload/car_images/1569501218.webp" 
            alt="Aston Martin DB9" 
            width="508" 
            height="340" 
            layout="responsive">
            <amp-img fallback 
                src="test/assets/img/upload/car_images/1569501218.png" 
                alt="Aston Martin DB9" 
                width="508" 
                height="340" 
                layout="responsive">
            </amp-img>
        </amp-img>
        <h4 class="center-text small-text red">Aston Martin DB9</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I can give working URLs if required but I don't understand/can't find any information on what would be causing this v0.js:127 error solely on iOS devices.

Comment: Does Safari support `webp`? On the `iPhone` does fallback to `1569501218.png` work?

Comment: @JayGray Safari does not support .webp as far as I know, it does fallback to the .png though. However, even with fallback it doesn't display the images.

Comment: suggestion: remove the `webp` and run only `png`. If you still get the `js:127` message we have another problem. if you get a clean runtime, submit the issue to https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues - I expect that Google will jump on this issue.

Comment: @JayGray have tried removing fallback and removing link for testing and still not working. I will post it as an issue and see what they come back with.

Comment: Have since tested on a few other iOS browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and UC Browser... Chrome and Firefox don't work either with the same v0.js:127 error, however UC Browser does show the images!

Comment: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24921